"Why there is no X?" vs "Why is there no X?"
Here are the two ways to ask the same question:

If <something is true>, [then] why there's no roof?
If <something is true>, [then] why is there no roof?

([then] is only for clarification, in writing it is omitted)
Q1: do both 1 and 2 mean the same and make sense to you?
Q2: does 1 or 2 sounds broken to a native speaker? (I mean countries where English is the main language, like Britain, USA, English speaking Canada, Australia, New Zealand). In other words, would you as a native speaker be surprised to hear something like this from another native speaker? Like a discomfort, ringing a bell, thinking "is this man a foreign spy?"
Q3: same as Q2, but would you cringe to read something like this in a fiction book?
Q4: same as Q3, but for historically non-English countries like India, or generally your impression as an internet user. I believe internet English is its own language, so non-native perspective is also interesting.
I am asking because I've noticed that ChatGPT corrects 1 -> 2, and my intuition says otherwise. My intuition comes from 15+ years of reading technical and fictional literature, browsing forums, and watching media in English, but I am by no means a scholar of English and don't live in an English-speaking country.
I've been told to read Why is the structure interrogative-which-word – subject – verb (including question mark) being used so often? Is it grammatical? but it is too technical for me, couldn't follow through.
If it really belongs to English-learners please tell and I will move it.

This question is similar to: NICE Properties of Auxiliary Verbs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. [Subject-auxiliary] "Inversion" is a property of the rule of Question Formation. Forming a question in English usually involves inversion of the subject and the first auxiliary, and thus requires an auxiliary verb. Again, if there is none, 'do' is supplied. [John Lawler] See ...

also Why is the structure {interrogative which-word}-{subject}-{verb} {including question mark} being used so often? eg 'Why Batman went to dinner with the Joker?!' ... << This type of deletion is common in say headlines and captions, being economical as regards space, and punchy. >> It can also, in the correct context, be a totally acceptable echo of a question (John Bollinger's 'Alice' quote, for instance).

Eff it, you can say anything is informal talk in any language, hand gestures included. Don't make it right.

I'd suggest this belongs on English Language Learners if you're asking how to form a question from "there is no roof because..." But if you have some other issue behind your question, please explain. How informal do you want?

@EdwinAshworth my experience suggests that it is particularly a feature of Indian English, or at least speakers of Indian English account for probably 95% of the instances I notice.  Uprooted: in standard English, without inversion, you get a relative clause, as in "the lack of a tip explains why there's no roof" or "...explains why there isn't a roof." To have a question, you need inversion: "why is there no roof?" Or "why isn't there a roof?"  Edwin Ashworth: if there's no punctuation, I'd also read a headline such as "why X went to dinner with Y" as a relative clause.

Yes, @phoog, there do seem to be confusing examples standard in one region but largely unacceptable in others. I think we can still expect UK and US 'standard practice' (which themselves aren't totally defined) to be the default requirements on ELU for examples not caveatted  Indian-English, Australian-English, Irish-English etc. And 'standard' English for those not caveatted 'Scottish-English' etc.

The mistake in 1) is typical of many non-native speakers. Even in India, there are those who are fluent and speak standard English. I hear non-native Spanish or Portuguese speakers speaking English who make this type of mistake all the time. This is a typical non-native mistake. Not a dialectal difference (Indian English).

In the title, the correct and more grammatical way to say it is the second one. "Is" should be placed, because if not, the sentence would have more errors versus the other one. But if it is, it should be more "front" of the sentence.
Example of this:
"Why is that so scrambled?"
vs "Why that is so scrambled?"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
